# fragment with the listview is not being replaced by the fragment with the textview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to have a activity with a image and then two fragments, one fragment with a list view and other fragment with a textview.

So, when the image is clicked i want to show the fragment with the list view and when the item on the fragment is clicked i want to replace the fragment with the listview with the fragment with the textview showing the text of the clicked list item.

Im doing this with the code below, but its not working, when an item of the list item is clicked the fragment with the listview is not replaced by the fragment with the textview so the list item text dont appears.

Main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ImageView img;


        FragmentManager fragmentManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }

        private void addFragment() {
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.listviewInFragment, fragment, "frag");
            transaction.commit();
        }


        public void AddFragmentList(View view) {
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.container, new FragmentA(), "frag");
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

main activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/image"
        android:onClick="AddFragmentList"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="71dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="390dp">

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment with the list view:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment{


    private ListView listItems;


    private String[] items = {
            "item1",
            "item2",
            "item3",
            "item4"
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        listItems = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listviewInFragment);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);


        listItems.setAdapter(adapter);


        listItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int positionCode = i;
                String clickedValue = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);


                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), clickedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("clickedValue", clickedValue);

                FragmentA fragA = new FragmentA();
                fragA.setArguments(b);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragA);


            }

        });
    }

}
```

Fragment with the list view xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0ff">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/listviewInFragment"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment with the text view:

```
public class fragmentb extends Fragment {

    private TextView tv;
    Intent intent;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

        return view;

        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Bundle b = this.getArguments();
        if(b != null){
            String clickedValue =b.getString("clickedValue");
            tv.setText(clickedValue);
        }

    }
}
```

Fragment with the text view xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
         />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may help you

```
listItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            int positionCode = i;
            String clickedValue = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);


            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), clickedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("clickedValue", clickedValue);


             FragmentB fragb = new FragmentB();
             FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
             FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
             fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragb);
             fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working when a item on the listview is clicked the fragmentb with the textview dont appears only the listview.

Comment: Is fragmentb is called or not

Comment: No, it dont appears.

Comment: @JonD now try my updated answer this may be work today i am making so many mistakes in my answes